# Inequality about Holder semi norm and Lp norm of a weak derivative on a Sobolev function.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, functional-inequalities

Let $p>n$ and $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

If 
$$
\sup_{x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}\leq C\|Du\|_{L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}
$$
 for $u\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with $C$ : independent of $u$,

then want to show that 
$$
\alpha=1-\frac{n}{p}
$$
This statement looks like a inverse of [Morrey's inequailty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Morrey.27s_inequality).

---

Next is what I've done for this question : 
By Fundamental theorem of Calculus, 
$$
u(x)-u(y)=\int_{C_{x,y}}(Du)
$$
 where $C_{x,y}$ is a line from $x$ to $y$.

Then, by Jensen's Inequality, 
$$
|u(x)-u(y)|^{p}=\left(\int_{C_{x,y}}(Du)\right)^{p}\leq\left(\int_{C_{x,y}}(Du)^{p}\right).
$$
 And then what can I do next?

Comment: My argument is kinda wrong. It goes wrong way. I guess in order to use Morrey's inequality, I should suppose$ \alpha$ is not equal to $1-n/p$....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a dilation argument here: let $u$ be a smooth cutoff, supported in $B(0,1)$, with $u(0)=1$ and $$\int_{B(0,1)}|Du|^p=1.$$ For $\lambda>0$, set $$u_{\lambda}(x)=u(\lambda x).$$ Note then that $$\sup_{x,y\in\mathbb R^n}\frac{|u_{\lambda}(x)-u_{\lambda}(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}\geq\frac{|u_{\lambda}(e_1/\lambda)-u_{\lambda}(0)|}{|e_1/\lambda|^{\alpha}}=\frac{|u(e_1)-u(0)|}{\lambda^{-\alpha}}=\lambda^{\alpha},$$ and $$\int_{\mathbb R^d}|Du_{\lambda}|^p=\int_{\mathbb R^d}|\lambda Du(\lambda x)|^p\,dx=\lambda^{p-d}\int_{\mathbb R^d}|Du|^p=\lambda^{p-d}.$$ Then, your inequality applied to $u_{\lambda}$ shows that $$\lambda^{\alpha}\leq \sup_{x,y\in\mathbb R^n}\frac{|u_{\lambda}(x)-u_{\lambda}(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}}\leq C\|Du_{\lambda}\|_p=C\lambda^{1-\frac{d}{p}},$$ or, equivalently, $$\lambda^{\alpha-1+\frac{d}{p}}\leq C.$$ Letting $\lambda\to \infty$ and $\lambda\to 0$, the last inequality shows that $\alpha=1-\frac{d}{p}$.

Comment: How fast you are.. Is this question is that easy? or is it duplicated? OMG thanks.

Comment: Those types of arguments are pretty standard; they are usually used to find the correct exponents for which various inequalities work.

Comment: As you say so, A same argument comes up in my mind, which is a general GNS inequality for $p>n$. I chose such $\gamma$ like that! Thanks! Could you give me another example using above 'correct exponents' argument?

Comment: One other example is the Sobolev inequality for $p<n$.

Comment: Do you mean when we choose $p^{*}=\frac{np}{n-p}$ ?

Comment: Yes, this is the one I am referring to.

Comment: Question : $|u(e_{1})−u(0)|$=1. Why does this equality hold?

Comment: Because $u$ is supported in $B(0,1)$, so $u(e_1)=0$, and $u(0)=1$.

Comment: How could we suppose those? Is it because Sobolev function is approximated by compact smooth functions? How did you assume $u(0)=1$?

Comment: $u$ is just a compactly supported function that satisfies those properties; its construction should not be very hard to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48817/discussion-between-heonjin-ha-and-detnvvp).